# Python find and return a string inside a string

Tags: python, string, find

Hello I have some string look like that:

```
"Alex_Hon::Chapman_x_voble_DOE2_SUB_mikaj"
```

I need to find a way to return the SUB string. 
The problem is that before that the DOE2 is changing all the time and can be also DOE23 or DOE 4546...
How Can I do that with python? 
Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "Alex_Hon::Chapman_x_voble_DOE2_SUB_mikaj"

m = re.search(r"DOE\d+_(.*?)_",s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
SUB
```